# Obtener último caracter de string - GO

Tags: string, go

Quiero saber como puedo obtener el último caracter de cualquier string con GO.
Hasta ahora lo único que pude hacer es obtener cada caracter de un string.

```
for i := 0; i < len(palabra); i++ {
    fmt.Println(string(len(palabra) [i]))
}
```

Comment: Podrias mostrar que intentaste o investigaste al respecto hasta ahora?

Comment: `string(palabra[len(palabra) - 1])`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como es bien sabido en Go Puedes extraer Sub-Slices Siguiendo la nomenclatura Slice[ValorInicial:ValorFinal] y a su vez sabemos que los Strings son un Slice de Caracteres, Porque no hacer lo mismo?

```
package main

import ("fmt")

func main() {
    val := "hola como, estas amigo?"
    fmt.Println(val[len(val)-1:])
}
```

En este caso nuestro slice se llama **val**, Obtenemos el ultimo elemento con **len(val)-1** (Nota: El metodo **len** retorna el tamaño de un Slice en este caso -1 porque deseamos obtener el ultimo elemento)

Aca te dejo una solucion Online para que revises: [Ejemplo](https://play.golang.org/p/O93ln-dXVMW)
Y una Documentacion Oficial sobre slices en go: [Slices: Usos](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

Comment: Ok, @gbianchi Gracias por la sugerencia, Ya lo he hecho. Saludos.

Comment: @BautistaMoran esta respuesta es más apropiada que la que tu has puesto ya que obtener la longitud de un string es mucho más optimo que iterarlo entero. Me gustaría añadir que también se podría extraer solo el ultimo elemento (`val[len(val)-1]`) pero eso te daría una runa (el tipo char de Go) y tendrias que volverlo a convertirlo a string (`string(val[len(val)-1])`, que es exactamente lo mismo que `(val[len(val)-1:]`)

Answer (score 2):

Ya lo resolví, asigné una variable que contenga cada letra al iterar y por lo tanto su valor, al terminar la iteración, sería la última letra. Dejo el código.

```
g := ""
for r := 0; r < len(palabra); r++ {
    g = string(len(palabra) [r])
}
fmt.Println(g)
```

Comment: recuerda que aparte de que es válido responder a tu pregunta, opcionalmente puedes **aceptarla** dando clic en la *palomita del lado izquierdo* para que se identifique como resuelta

Comment: Sí, pero puedo aceptarla recien en 21 horas.